# Split comma separated values into newlines on foreach loop - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

I have data on different variables and I am combining those variables using `PSObject`. Since I need to use `foreach` loop, I am getting the multiple values on `$repo.name` column but the other two columns `$group_id` & `$group.name` are single values.

'

```
$all = foreach($group in $all_groups)
    {
        $group_id = $group.id
        $uri = "xxx/reports"
        $repo = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri –Headers $auth_header –Method GET).value
        New-Object -Typename PSObject -Property @{
        Group = $group_ID
        GroupName = $group.name
        DisplayName = ($repo.name -join ',')
       } | Select-Object Group,GroupName, DisplayName '
```

I am getting below result but my expected result is different.

Current Result

```
Group GroupName DisplayName
----- --------- -----------
A     A0001     A1, A2, A3, A4
B     B0001     B1, B2, B3, B4
```

Expected Result

```
Group GroupName DisplayName
----- --------- -----------
A     A0001     A1
A     A0001     A2
A     A0001     A3
A     A0001     A4
B     B0001     B1
B     B0001     B2
B     B0001     B3
B     B0001     B4
```

Comment: It looks like ```$repo.name``` is an array, and the line ```DisplayName = ($repo.name -join ',')``` is where your problem is. You need to iterate over each item in ```$repo.name``` and create a new ```PSObject``` for each item

Answer (score 0):

If not massaging `$group.ID` otherwise, there is no need to copy it to another variable

As per [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton)s good hint,
and using the simpler `[PSCustomObject]`:

```bsh
$all = foreach($group in $all_groups) {
    $uri  = "xxx/reports"
    $repo = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri –Headers $auth_header –Method GET).value
    foreach($repoName in $repo.Name){
        [PCustomObject]@{
            Group       = $group.ID
            GroupName   = $group.Name
            DisplayName = $repoName
        }
    }
}
$all
```